# Fix Angular sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting, angularjs

[Angular](http://angularjs.org/) sorts "Åland Islands" after "Zimbabwe". I would like to fix this in a global way. Rather than creating a custom sort function and specifying it in every [`orderBy`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3aorderBy) filter, I would like to somehow globally patch the default sort function. Is this possible?

By first normalizing both strings with the following function, the problem is fixed:

```
function norm(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  str = str.replace(/\\s/g, "");
  str = str.replace(/[àáâãäå]/g, "a");
  str = str.replace(/æ/g, "ae");
  str = str.replace(/ç/g, "c");
  str = str.replace(/[èéêë]/g, "e");
  str = str.replace(/[ìíîï]/g, "i");
  str = str.replace(/ñ/g, "n");
  str = str.replace(/[òóôõö]/g, "o");
  str = str.replace(/œ/g, "oe");
  str = str.replace(/[ùúûü]/g, "u");
  str = str.replace(/[ýÿ]/g, "y");
  str = str.replace(/\\W/g, "");
  return str;
}
```

I'm hoping there's a way to do this once in Angular and never worry about it again.

Comment: Is creating a [custom filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.creating_filters), say "betterOrderBy", acceptable?

Comment: I believe angularjs uses javascript native compare operators.

Comment: @MarkRajcok, that's a great idea. Sounds perfect as long as, other than this comparison fix, `betterOrderBy` behaves the same as `orderBy`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can normalize it yourself:

```
var normalize = function(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase().
             replace(/[àáâãäå]/g, "a");
             // ...
};

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {name: 'Åland Islands'},
    // ...
  ];

  $scope.normalizedName = function(item) {
    return normalize(item.name);
  };
});
```

And then use in html:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:normalizedName">{{item.name}}</li>
```

Here's the whole example on [plunker](http://beta.plnkr.co/edit/PcnX6Mm973hmbRczEsPr?p=preview).

Comment: Vojta, this makes it so easy to affect the sort order that I don't really need to do it in a global way.

Answer (score 3):

As per the comments on the question, create a custom filter.  Inject the orderBy filter into this custom filter to not duplicate what orderBy already does:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
filter('betterOrderBy', function(orderByFilter) {
    return function(input, arg1, arg2) {
        var copy_of_input = angular.copy(input)
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            copy_of_input[i]['orig'] = input[i];
            str = copy_of_input[i][arg1].toLowerCase();
            str = str.replace(/[àáâãäå]/g, "a");
            // ...
            copy_of_input[i][arg1] = str.replace(/\\W/g, "");
        }
        var normalized_sorted = orderByFilter(copy_of_input, arg1, arg2);
        var normalized_sorted_orig = [];
        angular.forEach(normalized_sorted, function(obj, i) {
            normalized_sorted_orig.push(obj.orig)
        })
        return normalized_sorted_orig;
    }
});
```

Use it as follows:

```
Better sort: {{myArrayOfObjects | betterOrderBy:'name'}}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/TaHEt/).

Comment: Changing the content of the array in a "orderBy"? Feels like there could be unexpected side effects

Comment: @Liviu, good point.  I changed the code to create a copy first and then use the copy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @MarkRajcok. It looks like this filter ends up lower casing the names not only for sorting purposes, but also in the output.

Comment: @Christopher, yeah, for some reason I lost sight of the fact that the output text should be the same as the original.  I modified my filter.  It should do what you want now.  I updated the answer's sample code and the fiddle.

Comment: @MarkRajcok I love this solution! Do you know how to do the same for filter? I tried with no success...

Comment: @nochen, I don't quite understand your question.  We are creating a custom filter here, so there is no need to override `filter` itself, if that is what you are asking.  Your custom filter can do whatever it wants with the array of objects.

Comment: @MarkRajcok I'm talking about search text https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter This filter iterates through arrays and objects but is strict with accents... Is there an easy way to change that just as you did with orderBy?